# Custom Http headers in Angular 5

Tags: http-headers, angular5, angular-http-interceptors

How to add authorization and custom headers using interceptors. please check the demo link [stackBlitz](https://angular5-http-headers.stackblitz.io)

Please refer the console screenshot for your reference [browser console-request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6KPz.jpg)

And the custom headers are added in

> access-control-request-headers:authkey,content-type,deviceid

I want the headers to be added as part of header, not inside access-control-request-headers.

Angular Version : 5

Please suggest me on this

Answer (score 0):

The request in your screenshot is not the actual request you’re adding headers to —  it’s the OPTIONS pre-flight request made by your browser. Some browsers force this behavior when making a cross-origin request.

Are you getting an error response? I suspect what you’re actually encountering is a CORS issue.

EDIT 1: I don’t know what your stack looks like, but the following article helped me with my Angular CORS issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

In my case, I avoided having to make a pre-flight request entirely by changing the content-type (from application/Json) to text/plain.

> **Preflight Requests**
>
> For some CORS requests, the browser sends an
>   additional request, called a "preflight request", before it sends the
>   actual request for the resource. The browser can skip the preflight
>   request if the following conditions are true:
>
> The request method is GET, HEAD, or POST, and
>
> The application doesn't set any request headers other than Accept,
>   Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, or Last-Event-ID, and
>
> The Content-Type header (if set) is one of the following:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the above points i got to know, No custom headers can be set in HTTP request to avoid pre-flight request. So is there any workaround i can set custom header for authentication and get API response.

Comment: "401 Unauthorized" is the error. As I'm trying to send ID and token as header to authenticate for affiliate program.

Comment: When you make your request, have you specified requestOptions with the withCredentials member set to true? https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions The docs are annoyingly vague about what this actually does, but I know my requests wouldn't authorize without it.

Comment: Hey Dinesh, did you have any success with this? If you feel my response was helpful, please mark it as an answer. Thanks!